# Disable screen saver during install/initial setup

Tags: command-line, rhel, systemd, screensaver, gsettings

I need to disable all screen blanking/locking as part of os (rhel7.3) install. After searching I have found that

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

works when testing this from a graphical terminal after install. However, when I do this from the scripts run as initial setup, it fails.

I have tried to do it as part of a script that is run in runlevel 3 at the end of installation, that fails with:

```
dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=(long hex id here) --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

and to make a oneshot systemd service `ssoff.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable screen blanking
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

but I get the same error message in the log shown by `systemctl status ssoff`.
(I realize that this will run on each boot which is not The Right Way, but I figured if it worked it would be Good Enough.)

It seems that the system is somehow not ready for this command in these situations? How can I achieve this without manually doing it at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Both gsettings and dconf need to have DBus active.

I guess it might work like this (not tested though):

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable screen blanking
[Service]
Type=dbus
Busname=org.example.ssoff
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Also available to do is `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay 'uint32 0'`